# configuring logback programmatically

Tags: logging, logback

I'm truying to configure logback grammatically to use the SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.

I'm trying to test it with log file of 10KB and 3 files as limit.

For some reason it fails.

What am I doing wrong??

Here's my code:

```
class LogbackLogger implements ILogger {
private String componentName;
private Logger logger;

public LogbackLogger(String name) {
    componentName = "[" + name + "]";
    this.logger = ((Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(componentName));
}

public void info(String msg) {
    logger.info(msg);
}

public void debug(String msg) {
    logger.debug(msg);
}

public void warning(String msg) {
    logger.warn(msg);
}

public void error(String msg) {
    logger.error(msg);
}

public void error(String msg, Throwable t) {
    logger.error(msg, t);
}

public void dispose() {
    // Stop all appenders, threads etc. This command is take from the
    // "Stopping logback-classic" section in here:
    // http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    loggerContext.stop();
}

public void setLevel(Level level)
{
    this.logger.setLevel(level);
}

public void removeConsoleAppender() {
    this.logger.detachAppender("Console");
}

public void addConsoleAppender() {
    if (this.logger.getAppender("Console") != null) {
        return;
    }
    ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent> consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
    consoleAppender.setName("Console");
    consoleAppender.setTarget("System.out");
    consoleAppender.setEncoder(getEncoder(this.logger.getLoggerContext()));
    consoleAppender.setContext(this.logger.getLoggerContext());
    consoleAppender.start();
    this.logger.addAppender(consoleAppender);
}

public void addFileAppender(String fileName, long logLimitInKB, int fileCount) {
    if (this.logger.getAppender("File") != null) {
        log("FileAppender already exists");
        return;
    }

    log("About to create FileAppender. fileName:" + fileName);
    FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = createFileAppender(fileCount, logLimitInKB, fileName);
    fileAppender.setEncoder(getEncoder(this.logger.getLoggerContext()));
    fileAppender.start();
    this.logger.addAppender(fileAppender);
}

private Encoder<ILoggingEvent> getEncoder(LoggerContext loggerContext) {
    final PatternLayoutEncoder encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder();
    encoder.setContext(loggerContext);
    encoder.setPattern("%date{ISO8601} %-5level [%thread] %logger{35} %msg%n");
    encoder.setOutputPatternAsHeader(false);
    encoder.start();

    return encoder;
}

private FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> createFileAppender(int fileCount, long logLimitInKB, String fileName) {
    if (fileCount <= 1) {
        log("Creating FileAppender");
        FileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new FileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();
        fileAppender.setName("File");
        fileAppender.setFile(fileName);
        fileAppender.setAppend(false);
        fileAppender.setPrudent(false);
        fileAppender.setContext(this.logger.getLoggerContext());
        return fileAppender;
    }

    log("Creating RollingFileAppender");
    RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent> fileAppender = new RollingFileAppender<ILoggingEvent>();

    fileAppender.setContext(this.logger.getLoggerContext());
    fileAppender.setName("File");
    fileAppender.setFile(fileName);
    fileAppender.setAppend(false);
    fileAppender.setPrudent(false);

    FixedWindowRollingPolicy rollingPolicy = new FixedWindowRollingPolicy();
    rollingPolicy.setContext(this.logger.getLoggerContext());
    rollingPolicy.setParent(fileAppender);
    rollingPolicy.setMinIndex(1);
    rollingPolicy.setMaxIndex(fileCount - 1);
    rollingPolicy.setFileNamePattern(fileName + "%i.log");
    fileAppender.setRollingPolicy(rollingPolicy);

    TriggeringPolicy<ILoggingEvent> triggerPolicy = new SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy(logLimitInKB +" kb");

    fileAppender.setTriggeringPolicy(triggerPolicy);

    triggerPolicy.start();
    rollingPolicy.start();

    return fileAppender;
}

private void log(String msg)
{
    System.out.println("#############################################################");
    System.out.println(msg);
    System.out.println("#############################################################");

}
```

}

I'll appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my problem was related to configuration. It turned out that my issue was that due to a bug in my code, each logger created a new instance of of RollingFileAppender.

When multiple RollingFileAppenders exists & watch the same file, they all have open handles to the file, making it impossible to rename it (since other appenders have an open handle to it).

I was able to track find my issue by printing status information from logback.
Here's the code I've used to print it:

```
private void printLogbackInternalState(String prefix){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("<"+ prefix+"> Internal state:" + System.lineSeparator());
    for(Status status : this.logger.getLoggerContext().getStatusManager().getCopyOfStatusList()){
        sb.append(status.getOrigin() + " - " + status.getMessage()+ System.lineSeparator());
    }

    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

I've used it right after the code that created an appender and then I was able to notice that I have several instances & an error message that indicates that it can't rename the file.

Hope this will help anyone :)